# How can I call Cypher queries via Neo4j REST API using Ext.Ajax.request?

Tags: ajax, rest, extjs, neo4j, cypher

I'm having problems when making a request to the Neo4j REST API using a cypher query from Extjs' function Ext.Ajax.request, here's my code:

```
values.query="MATCH (x { username: {username}, password: {password} }) RETURN x";

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
    params: values,
    success: successCallback,
    failure: failureCallback
});
```

I'm getting the next response from de server

```
responseText: "{↵  "message" : "The statement has been closed.",↵  "exception" : "BadInputException"...
```

Comment: How are you passing the param values (username, password)?

Comment: I'm concerned about security when passing those values through ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
MATCH (x) where x.username= {username} and  x.password= {password}  RETURN x
```

Try to use labels as well, since working with only node properties is way too slow.
You could set a label such as account on node x.
With

```
MATCH (x) where x.username= {username} and  x.password= {password} set (x:account) RETURN x
```

And when looking for it you would use

```
MATCH (x:account) where x.username= {username} and  x.password= {password}  RETURN x
```

Hope it helps